# Restrict Attachment File Size Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Currently I have a database system that has been designed to log the calls coming into a department. To help other agents on the phone system with information I allowed for attachments so photographs, letters etc. To allow for attachments to be added there is an attachments control on the form to allow for additional documentation to be added as mentioned above.

The problem is, I have found a lot of people are using the system to store large copies of manuals. Which is causing the file size of the database to shoot up exponentially.

What I would like to know is, is it possible to restrict the file size of an attachment through VBA? For example restrict it to 6MB.

Comment: Please see modified above. "To allow for attachments to be added there is an attachments control on the form to allow for additional documentation to be added as mentioned above. "

Comment: I have no expertise on this point, so I present this humbly as a comment.  It seems Access' built-in feature is serviceable as a photo-handler, but not as a document manager; and I'd have to guess your current issue will not be the last.  Users have recommended a point-to-file record instead of the file-attach feature.

Comment: In support of above comment, see http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/141654-MS-Access-2010-Adding-Attachments-from-Form-using-Unbound-Field-and-VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question the following code will return the file size but as others mentioned above I don't think I would want to store attachments in an Access database your database will grow quickly and may become unstable.

```
Private Sub CheckFileSize(strMyFile)
  Dim objFileSys As Scripting.FileSystemObject
  Dim objMyFile As File
  Set objFileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set objMyFile = objFileSys.GetFile(strMyFile)
  If objMyFile.Size > 6000000 then
    MsgBox "File is too big.", vbokonly
  Else
    MsgBox "File is OK.", vbokonly
  End If
  Set objFileSys = Nothing
  Set objMyFile = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you this will be very helpful to deter the users. The attachments was only added as a feature mainly for small pictures or text files. This was communicated to the users not to store large files but as user do they never listen. I appreciate the code thank you i will give it a try.

Comment: Your welcome, if this works for you please check as working.  Also you will have to reference "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" the dll is scrrun.dll and if you are running Windows 7 it should be in your SysWOW64 folder.